# Task/Job Scheduling for a Sound Xamarin Cross-Platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, scheduled-tasks, cross-platform, background-process

I am developing a timer app, using scheduled push notifications, and I want the timer sound to play at the scheduled time of the push notification as well. I want the sounds to play even if the app is closed or terminated. My notifications already work on this premise, so I know it is possible to run a task after the app is closed. I already have sound functionality, while the app is running. So, if the user had closed the app, but had a timer set to go off, they would receive a notification and the timer sound would play. This timer sound is an MP3 file that I had been passing in as a stream, to play the sound in the app, but now I want the sound to play if the app is terminated.  I have no idea how to go about scheduling a sound to be played, regardless of app state.

Im using the Shiny nuget package for my cross platform push notifications, but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: You keep asking the same question and it keeps getting closed.  Please stop.

Comment: @Jason how do you do this then? Is it possible or not? I am asking about playing a sound while the app is not running.

Comment: I highly doubt it.